# Getting memory leak when converting HTML string to AttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, nsattributedstring

Getting memory leak when converting HTML string to AttributedString using below String extension

Usage:

```
self.lblHeader.attributedText = "<H1>Hello world</H1><h2><b>, abc</b><h2>".html2AttributedString
```

String extension for converting HTML to attributed string

```
extension String {
    var html2AttributedString: NSMutableAttributedString? {
        autoreleasepool {
            let htmlData = self.data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf16.rawValue))
            let options = [
                NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
                NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html
            ] as [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any]
            let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
                data: htmlData ?? Data(),
                options: options,
                documentAttributes: nil)
        
           return attributedString
       }
   }
}
```

As I found a memory leak due to below the line:

```
let options = [
            NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:
            NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html
        ] as [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any]
```

is there any alternative solution, let me know.

Comment: Which object did you find to be leaking? The line you're referring to create a `Dictionary` with `struct`s in it, so nothing can leak on that line, since there are no reference types involved.

Comment: @DávidPásztor, there is a display memory leak on instruments. please check this [image](https://ibb.co/W5fgXP3) for more reference.

Comment: @DávidPásztor it might be because the returned attributed string is leaking / not being released. Don't forget that a `Dictionary` keeps a reference to its storage and uses "copy on write" to maintain value semantics.

Comment: @JeremyP, memory leak due to NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType:  NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html this attribute only, if remove it then there is no any memory leak

Comment: @JeremyP the string isn't stored in the dictionary though. I'd suspect the leaks instrument is incorrectly pointing to the leak line.

Comment: @SK I'd suggest you have a look at the memory usage in Xcode itself, not in instruments to see if the memory usage is actually increasing if you keep entering and exiting the feature. Just to ensure that what you're seeing isn't a red herring, but an actual leak.

Comment: I know this is quite old but I've been investigating the same issue looking at Instruments it appears that this might be a side-effect of some optimisations, for example, I can see Apple is using a WebKit WebView to render the HTML, WebViews are very expensive, so I'm wondering if this is loaded into memory once and then kept alive in order to do future HTML rendering to avoid constant cold initialisations of the web view.